# Specific method in object does not work

Tags: javascript

Im building a small cashRegister in javascript and have problems with a method i add. Cant seem to get it working. My consol prints the first two statements but does not do the last one. Any thoughts on what goes wrong?

```
var cashRegister = {
    total: 0,
    add: function(itemCost) {
        this.total += itemCost;
        this.lastTransactionAmount = itemCost;
    },
    scan: function(item, quantity) {
        switch (item) {
            case "eggs":
                this.add(0.98 * quantity);
                break;

            case "milk":
                this.add(1.23 * quantity);
                break;
        }
    },
    deleteLastTransaction: function() {
        this.total -= lastTransactionAmount;
    }
};
cashRegister.scan("eggs", 4);
cashRegister.scan("eggs", 2);
cashRegister.scan("milk", 2);
document.write("Total amount is: " + cashRegister.total + "</br>" + "Last transaction amount: " + cashRegister.lastTransactionAmount);
cashRegister.deleteLastTransaction();
document.write("The total amount is now: " + cashRegister.total);
```

Answer (score 5):

There's no variable `lastTransactionAmount`. The last function should be:

```
deleteLastTransaction: function() {
    if ('lastTransactionAmount' in this) {
        this.total -= this.lastTransactionAmount;
    }
}
```